# Use of debounce on Ext 3.4 framework

Tags: javascript, extjs, debouncing

I want to implement the debounce function on Ext.Button, so I extended it and override the onClick function, like this:

```
MyButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
    onClick:  function(e) {
        var that = this;
        var args = e;
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutDebounce);

        this.timeoutDebounce = setTimeout(function(){
                  MyButton.superclass.onClick.apply(that, [args])
        }, this.debounce);
    }
});
```

Debounce is a parameter passed on the x-type declaration.

The problem here is that the "args" parameter I'm passing to onClick has changed when it's called from "click" to "mouvemove" and it doesn't fire the events it should.

Is there a way to record the "e" parameter received in the function to pass to onClick on superclass?

Comment: You may want to look at `Ext.util.DelayedTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to setTimeout must be wrapped in order to keep the value presented in current scope:

```
function createCallback(args) {
  return function() {
    MyButton.superclass.onClick.apply(that, [args]);
  }
}
```

Also, e is passed by reference, so you need to create a copy of it. Using ExtJS, you can use Ext.apply method:

```
Ext.apply({}, e);
```

The full code should be:

```
var MyButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
  onClick: function(e) {
    var that = this;
    function createCallback(args) {
      return function() {
        MyButton.superclass.onClick.apply(that, [args]);
        // you can also use call since you know the arguments:
        // MyButton.superclass.onClick.call(that, args);
      }
    }

    clearTimeout(this.timeoutDebounce);

    var copy = Ext.apply({}, e);
    this.timeoutDebounce = setTimeout(createCallback(copy), this.debounce);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the object:

```
var args = Ext.apply({}, e);

this.timeoutDebounce = setTimeout((function(args){
    return function(){MyButton.superclass.onClick.apply(that, [args])};
})(args), this.debounce);
```